# invalid operands to binary ==

Tags: c

I have a program that I am trying to compile but it's showing me the compilation error : 
    at line 22 :  "invalid operands to binary ==" 
I searched through various available solutions but couldn't find solutions to my problem. The code is as follows :

```
      #include <stdio.h>

        typedef struct nx_string_t
        {
            char *buf;  
        }nx_string_t;

        typedef struct nx_value_t
        {
            union
                {
                nx_string_t strng;
                }
        } nx_value_t;

        void func(nx_value_t *vale);

        void func(nx_value_t *vale)
        {
             if(vale->strng == NULL) // Error occurs here.
             {
                  printf("its done");    
             }
        }
```

Comment: Please highlight line 22.

Comment: In case that's your actual code, I just want to say that words with rndmly delted vwels are mstly incmprehnsble. The mental effort required to understand them is nevr wrth the typing ffrt u sav.

Answer (score 4):

The member `strng` is of type `nx_string_t`, which is not a pointer.

You must compare against the pointer element inside:

```
if(value->strng.buf == NULL)
```

Comment: @user2074923, consider accepting unwinds answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison should be

```
if (vale->strng.buf == NULL)
```

`vale->strng` is of type `nx_string_t` which is not a pointer so can never be `NULL`.  It does however have a `buf` pointer member which could be `NULL`.